# C# snipping tool service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First of all this question is for education purpose.

My task is to do service that capture select part of screen like snipping tool in 
Win7 i manage to do this in win form and its work great but when i do it in service its return a black screen  i know the problem which is the the service run in a different session so my question is how to make the service run and return the user desktop
and the second question is how to listen to key press in service (i know how to do it in forms) any help please. And take your time. My form code:

```
private void CaptureScreen()
{
    this.Hide();
    Thread.Sleep(300);
    bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    bmpScreenshot.Save(DialogSave.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    pictureBox1.Image = bmpScreenshot;
    this.Show();
}

private static Image cropImage(Bitmap img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
    Bitmap bmpCrop = img.Clone(cropArea,
    img.PixelFormat);
    return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}

private Rectangle selectArea(int recX1, int recY1,int recX2,int recY2) 
{
    int width = recX2 - recX1;
    int height = recY2 - recY1;
    return new Rectangle(recX1, recY1, width, height);
}

private void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (x1 <= 0 || x2 <= 0 || y1 <= 0 || y2 <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select area first", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        Rectangle myrectangle = selectArea(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        Bitmap myImg = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filename);
        Image cr = cropImage(myImg, myrectangle);
        na = @"F:\\" + Counter + ".jpg";
        while (File.Exists(@"F:\\" + Counter + ".jpg"))
        {
            Counter++;
        }
        na = @"F:\\" + Counter + ".jpg";
        cr.Save(@"F:\\" + Counter++ + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox1.Image = cr;
        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\\";
        prc.Start();
        this.PrintScreennotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Save to" + na;
        this.PrintScreennotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Info";
        this.PrintScreennotifyIcon.Visible = true;
        this.PrintScreennotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add capitals, periods and other punctuation such as questionmarks.

Comment: @Erno: I did some try to fix that

Comment: Depends on the OS. This will never work on a Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

On some versions of Windows you may be able to get the service to see a desktop, however which desktop should it choose if there are multiple people logged in?

Basically, your solution can't run as a service if you want propert interaction with the desktop.

Also, for the same reason, you shouldn't be spawning message boxes, as there may be no one that can click OK and allow program execution to continue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the option "allow service interact with the desktop" and select the Local Account (everything at the services screen).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way is to make an app running minimize in taskbar and launched when the computer start.

It's really less intrusive into the computer :).

Comment: i like this idea but how to something like this

Comment: You make a classic windows app'. While running, you change the `WindowState` to Minimized and the ShowInTaskBar to false.