# Best way/solution to display json data from a local winform .net app on angularJS web dashboard applicaiton

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, winforms, web-services

can u please help me out with the best solution how to do this?

- I have a windows form application, which is continuously doing something. (making screenshots and generating data) This app is running locally.
- So I dont want to use teamviewer from office just to see what my application is doing. I want to create an AngularJS Web Dashboard application (load it on a webhost) and display this winform data (in form of charts,..), so that I can access from everywere.

What is the best solution for this?

I have experience with AngularJS and parsing JSON-Files from a webserver.

I preffer creating/serialize a json file (each second) from my winform app and load it somewhere on webhost and then access this json file with http.get from my AngularJS application.

Is this a possible solution? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with making a Angular web app (although you don't need angular for this, you can use jquery to make a simple ajax call, seems like it would be quicker to add the jquery reference than to setup the angular scaffolding just for one or two ajax calls) to call a web request where the winforms app stores the data.

Ex. you can create a web request (or directory save) in winforms app to perform the 'snipping tool' action described here: [C# snipping tool service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802399/c-sharp-snipping-tool-service) and send the data to somewhere to store it. If the snipping tool doesn't work then probably use an export of the chart or data you are capturing. Then the web app can query that directory to retrieve (ajax/http get) whichever data you need.

I would advise clean up on that directory as it could become quite big if you are saving to it every few seconds or so.